# Pager is not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am facing a little problem while using the DataTables plugin.

When my page first loads, results are shown perfectly. But when I apply a filter, press the search button and the AJAX call is completed, that pager does not update and shows the same number of registries that in the beginning.

This is the source code that I am using for the AJAX call:

```
function GetRegisteredAdmonition(initialConsecutive, finalConsecutive, supervisorEmployeeNumber, bannedEmployeeNumber, disciplinaryAction, status, startDate, finalDate) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "reviewAdmonition.aspx/GetAdmonition",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        initialConsecutive: initialConsecutive,
        finalConsecutive: finalConsecutive,
        supervisorEmployeeNumber: supervisorEmployeeNumber,
        bannedEmployeeNumber: bannedEmployeeNumber,
        disciplinaryAction: disciplinaryAction,
        status: status,
        startDate: startDate,
        finalDate: finalDate
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: OnSuccessGetAdmonition
});}

function OnSuccessGetAdmonition(response) {
    $("#admonitionBody").empty();

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
    var xml = $(xmlDoc);

    console.log(response.d);

    $(xml).find("Table").each(function () {
        var consecutive = $(this).find('Folio').text();
        var supervisorEmployeeNumber = $(this).find('NóminaOriginador').text();
        var supervisorName = $(this).find('Originador').text();
        var bannedEmployeeNumber = $(this).find('NóminaAmonestado').text();
        var bannedEmployeeName = $(this).find('Amonestado').text();
        var action = $(this).find('MedidaDisciplinaria').text();
        var state = $(this).find('stepName').text();
        var creationDate = $(this).find('Fecha_x0020_creación').text().split('T')[0];

        switch (state) {
            case 'Esperando aprobación':
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + consecutive + '</td > <td>' + bannedEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + bannedEmployeeName + '</td> <td>' + supervisorEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + supervisorName + '</td> <td>' + action + '</td> <td>' + state + '</td> <td>' + creationDate + '</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white approveAdmonition"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check green"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white rejectAdmonition"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-undo orange"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white editAdmonition"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white cancelAdmonition"><i class="fa fa-trash text-danger"></i></button></td>').appendTo('#tblAdmonition');
                break;
            case 'Aprobada':
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + consecutive + '</td > <td>' + bannedEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + bannedEmployeeName + '</td> <td>' + supervisorEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + supervisorName + '</td> <td>' + action + '</td> <td>' + state + '</td> <td>' + creationDate + '</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white reprintAdmonition"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-print green"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-round btn-white editAdmonition"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil blue"></i></button></td>').appendTo('#tblAdmonition');
                break;
            case 'Rechazada':
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + consecutive + '</td > <td>' + bannedEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + bannedEmployeeName + '</td> <td>' + supervisorEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + supervisorName + '</td> <td>' + action + '</td> <td>' + state + '</td> <td>' + creationDate + '</td>').appendTo('#tblAdmonition');
                break;
            case 'Cancelada':
                $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + consecutive + '</td > <td>' + bannedEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + bannedEmployeeName + '</td> <td>' + supervisorEmployeeNumber + '</td> <td>' + supervisorName + '</td> <td>' + action + '</td> <td>' + state + '</td> <td>' + creationDate + '</td>').appendTo('#tblAdmonition');
                break;
        }
    });

    var table = $('#tblAdmonition').DataTable({
        retrieve: true,
        "language": {
            "url":"Scripts/Spanish.json"
        },
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    });
}
```

As you can see, I tried to clear the table body, but that did not work.

I am attaching some pictures to clarify the information. In the image you can see that there is only one registry in the table, but the pager is showing 3 more pages and a total of 25 registries.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You don't you use the API and `clear()` then `add()` the new rows and at the end `.draw()` ? See https://datatables.net/reference/api/

Comment: Hello @GabyakaG.Petrioli! Thanks for your response, let me re-read that link you proposed. Maybe there is something I missed.